# AJAX returning an error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to populate my dropdown using ajax but it returns an error.

Here is my js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

       $.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo base_url('Supplies_controller/getCategory'); ?>",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
           $(data).each(function(){
               $("#category").append($('<option>', {
                    value: this.id,
                    text: this.category,
                }));
             })
        },
        error: function(errorw) {
            alert("hi");
        }
      });
    });
 </script>
```

Here is my Supplies_controller

```
public function getCategory(){
    $categories = $this->supplies_model->getCategory();
    echo json_encode($categories);
}
```

And here is my Supplies_model

```
function getCategory(){
    $this->db->select('id, category');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $this->db->order_by("category", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

It executes the `alert("hi");` that is in my error function in java. I don't seem to see anything wrong about my code.

BTW, I am using Codeigniter 3.0.

If there is please help me see it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: replace your error part with `error:function(x,y,z){console.log(x+""+y+""+z)},`
And check whats the error AJAX is throwing ...

Comment: yes please, update your question with ajax error

Comment: @AmarShukla - `error:funciton`? spelling mistake!

Comment: @RamRaider : LOL! yes ...editted ! Thanks

Comment: It seems like the error is caused by a spelling mistake in other parts of my model. Sorry for causing trouble.

Comment: Return result into array return $query->result_array();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         $(data).each(function(){
           $("#category").append($('<option>', {
                value: this.id,
                text: this.category,
            }));
         });
```